# Probability and limit - proof of equality

Tags: probability, limits

Could anyone explain why this equality is true? Is there some intermediate step that could be used to prove it? If I were to guess, I'd guess it's certainly equal, but guessing is not enough I'm afraid.

$$P \left (X\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, t - \frac{1}{n}]\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(X \in (-\infty, t - \frac{1}{n}]\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, except measure theoretical discusses, that you know the probability function is countably additive, i.e for pairwise disjoint family of events $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we have $P(\bigcup A_n)=\sum_n P(A_n)$.

In general case, suppose you have the nested events $\{E_i\}$, i.e $E_n\subset E_{n+1}$, then by defining $E_0=\emptyset \wedge A_n:=E_n\setminus E_{n-1};n\geq1$, we'll have $\{A_n\}$s are pairwise disjoint and :

$\begin{align}P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n)=P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)-P(E_{n-1})&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(E_n)-P(\emptyset)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(E_n)\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Your sets are nested so the union is just the last set in the union for the finite unions, so the equality is justified.

Comment: by continuity of probability?